# How to convert two bytes to floating point number

Tags: vb.net, floating-point, binary

I have some legacy files that need mined for data. The files were created by Lotus123 Release 4 for DOS. I'm trying to read the files faster by parsing the bytes rather than using Lotus to open the files.

```
Dim fileBytes() As Byte = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(fiPath)

'I loop through all the data getting first/second bytes for each value
do ...
    Dim FirstByte As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(fileBytes(Index))
    Dim SecondByte As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(fileBytes(Index + 1))
loop ...
```

I can get integer values like this:

```
Dim value As Int16 = BitConverter.ToInt16(fileBytes, Index + 8) / 2
```

But floating numbers are more complicated. Only the smaller numbers are stored with two bytes. Larger values take 10 bytes, but that's another question. Here we only have smaller values with two bytes. Here are some sample values. I entered the byte values into Excel and use the =DEC2BIN() to convert to binary adding zeros on the left as needed to get 8 bits.

```
First   Second
Byte    Byte        Value   First   Byte    2nd     Byte

7       241     =   -1.2    0000    0111    1111    0001
254     255     =   -1      1111    1110    1111    1111
9       156     =   -0.8    0000    1001    1001    1100
9       181     =   -0.6    0000    1001    1011    0101
9       206     =   -0.4    0000    1001    1100    1110
9       231     =   -0.2    0000    1001    1110    0111
13      0       =   0       0000    1101    0000    0000
137     12      =   0.1     1000    1001    0000    1100
9       25      =   0.2     0000    1001    0001    1001
137     37      =   0.3     1000    1001    0010    0101
9       50      =   0.4     0000    1001    0011    0010
15      2       =   0.5     0000    1111    0000    0010
9       75      =   0.6     0000    1001    0100    1011
137     87      =   0.7     1000    1001    0101    0111
9       100     =   0.8     0000    1001    0110    0100
137     112     =   0.9     1000    1001    0111    0000
2       0       =   1       0000    0010    0000    0000
199     13      =   1.1     1100    0111    0000    1101
7       15      =   1.2     0000    0111    0000    1111
71      16      =   1.3     0100    0111    0001    0000
135     17      =   1.4     1000    0111    0001    0001
15      6       =   1.5     0000    1111    0000    0110
7       20      =   1.6     0000    0111    0001    0100
71      21      =   1.7     0100    0111    0001    0101
135     22      =   1.8     1000    0111    0001    0110
199     23      =   1.9     1100    0111    0001    0111
4       0       =   2       0000    0100    0000    0000
```

I'm hoping for a simple conversion method. Or maybe it'll be more complicated.

> I looked at [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal): "BCD was used in many early decimal computers, and is implemented in the instruction set of machines such as the IBM System/360 series" and [Intel BCD opcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_BCD_opcode)

I do not know if this is BCD or what it is. How do I convert the two bits into a floating point number?

Comment: Lotus 123 for DOS was originally written by Jonathan Sachs in Intel 8088 assembly language for the IBM PC. https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/107619/oh388js.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y

Comment: Wikipedia says release 2 "supported x87 math coprocessors" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_1-2-3#DOS
Also it says release 3 & 4 "were primarily written in C"

Comment: If they are .wk4 files then there is some information about that format at [Lotus 123 - .wk4 format](http://www.mettalogic.co.uk/tim/l123/l123r4.html). Or you might like to look at the souce code for [Gnumeric](http://www.gnumeric.org/) to see how they read .wk4 files.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Beautiful, looks promising. I'll check it out on Monday. Thanks.

Comment: @D_Bester I am running into trouble with the decoding of integers. Either the description of the format at the website is wrong or I slipped up translating to code. Could you add some more integers to your test data, please: `3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 32.0`?

Comment: @D_Bester Never mind, I realized my mistake in transforming the information at the website into code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a `VB.Net` translation of the `C` code [posted by njuffa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55083738/7444103).
The original `structure` has been substituted with a Byte array and the numeric data type adapted to .Net types. That's all.

```
Dim data As Byte(,) = New Byte(,) {
    {7, 241}, {254, 255}, {9, 156}, {9, 181}, {9, 206}, {9, 231}, {13, 0}, {137, 12}, {9, 25}, 
    {137, 37}, {9, 50}, {15, 2}, {9, 75}, {137, 87}, {9, 100}, {137, 112}, {2, 0}, {199, 13}, 
    {7, 15}, {71, 16}, {135, 17}, {15, 6}, {7, 20}, {71, 21}, {135, 22}, {199, 23}, {4, 0}
}

Dim byte1, byte2 As Byte
Dim word, code As UShort
Dim nValue As Integer
Dim result As Double

For i As Integer = 0 To (data.Length \ 2 - 1)
    byte1 = data(i, 0)
    byte2 = data(i, 1)
    word = (byte2 * 256US) + byte1
    If (word Mod 2) = 1 Then
        code = (word \ 2US) Mod 8US
        nValue = ((word \ 16) Xor 2048) - 2048
        Select Case code
            Case 0 : result = nValue * 5000
            Case 1 : result = nValue * 500
            Case 2 : result = nValue / 20
            Case 3 : result = nValue / 200
            Case 4 : result = nValue / 2000
            Case 5 : result = nValue / 20000
            Case 6 : result = nValue / 16
            Case 7 : result = nValue / 64
        End Select
    Else
        'unscaled 15-bit integer in h<15:1>. Extract, sign extend to 32 bits
        nValue = ((word \ 2) Xor 16384) - 16384
        result = nValue
    End If
    Console.WriteLine($"[{byte1,3:D}, {byte2,3:D}]  number = {nValue:X8} result ={result,12:F8}")
Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am very grateful for the VB.net translation! Works beautifully.

Comment: Yes, well, I'm glad it was helpful, but you really need to pick @njuffa answer as the good one. This is just a translation. I cannot take credit for this.

Answer (score 3):

I used the information from the [website](http://www.mettalogic.co.uk/tim/l123/l123r4.html) pointed out by Andrew Morton in comments. Basically the stored 16-bit quantity consists of either a 15-bit two's complement integer (when the lsb is 0) or a 12-bit two's complement integer plus a processing code indicating a scale factor to be applied to that integer (when the lsb is 1). I am not familiar with vb.net so am providing ISO-C code here. Program below successfully decodes all the data provided in the question.

Note: I am converting to an 8-byte `double` in code below, while the question suggests that the original conversion may have been to a 10-byte `long double` format (the 80-bit extended-precision format of the 8087 math coprocessor). It would seem like a good idea to try more test data to achieve full coverage of the eight scaling codes: Large integers like 1,000,000 and 1,000,000,000; decimal fractions like 0.0003, 0.000005, and 0.00000007; and binary fractions like 0.125 (1/8) and 0.046875 (3/64).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
    uint8_t byte1;
    uint8_t byte2;
} num;

num data[] = 
{
    {  7, 241}, {254, 255}, {  9, 156}, {  9, 181}, {  9, 206}, {  9, 231},
    { 13,   0}, {137,  12}, {  9,  25}, {137,  37}, {  9,  50}, { 15,   2},
    {  9,  75}, {137,  87}, {  9, 100}, {137, 112}, {  2,   0}, {199,  13},
    {  7,  15}, { 71,  16}, {135,  17}, { 15,   6}, {  7,  20}, { 71,  21},
    {135,  22}, {199,  23}, {  4,   0}
};

int data_count = sizeof (data) / sizeof (data[0]);

/* define operators that may look more familiar to vb.net programmers */
#define XOR  ^
#define MOD  %

int main (void)
{
    int i;
    uint8_t b1, b2;
    uint16_t h, code;
    int32_t n;
    double r;
    for (i = 0; i < data_count; i++) {
        b1 = data[i].byte1;
        b2 = data[i].byte2;
        /* data word */
        h = ((uint16_t)b2 * 256) + b1;
        /* h<0>=1 indicates stored integer needs to be scaled */
        if ((h MOD 2) == 1) {
            /* extract scaling code in h<3:1> */
            code = (h / 2) MOD 8; 
            /* scaled 12-bit integer in h<15:4>. Extract, sign-extend to 32 bits */
            n = (int32_t)((((uint32_t)h / 16) XOR 2048) - 2048);
            /* convert integer to floating-point */
            r = (double)n;
            /* scale based on scaling code */
            switch (code) {
            case 0x0:  r = r * 5000;  break;
            case 0x1:  r = r * 500;   break;
            case 0x2:  r = r / 20;    break;
            case 0x3:  r = r / 200;   break;
            case 0x4:  r = r / 2000;  break;
            case 0x5:  r = r / 20000; break;
            case 0x6:  r = r / 16;    break;
            case 0x7:  r = r / 64;    break;
            };
        } else {
            /* unscaled 15-bit integer in h<15:1>. Extract, sign extend to 32 bits */
            n = (int32_t)((((uint32_t)h / 2) XOR 16384) - 16384);
            /* convert integer to floating-point */
            r = (double)n;
        }
        printf ("[%3d,%3d]  n=%08x  r=% 12.8f\n", b1, b2, n, r);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output of this program is as follows:

```
[  7,241]  n=ffffff10  r= -1.20000000
[254,255]  n=ffffffff  r= -1.00000000
[  9,156]  n=fffff9c0  r= -0.80000000
[  9,181]  n=fffffb50  r= -0.60000000
[  9,206]  n=fffffce0  r= -0.40000000
[  9,231]  n=fffffe70  r= -0.20000000
[ 13,  0]  n=00000000  r=  0.00000000
[137, 12]  n=000000c8  r=  0.10000000
[  9, 25]  n=00000190  r=  0.20000000
[137, 37]  n=00000258  r=  0.30000000
[  9, 50]  n=00000320  r=  0.40000000
[ 15,  2]  n=00000020  r=  0.50000000
[  9, 75]  n=000004b0  r=  0.60000000
[137, 87]  n=00000578  r=  0.70000000
[  9,100]  n=00000640  r=  0.80000000
[137,112]  n=00000708  r=  0.90000000
[  2,  0]  n=00000001  r=  1.00000000
[199, 13]  n=000000dc  r=  1.10000000
[  7, 15]  n=000000f0  r=  1.20000000
[ 71, 16]  n=00000104  r=  1.30000000
[135, 17]  n=00000118  r=  1.40000000
[ 15,  6]  n=00000060  r=  1.50000000
[  7, 20]  n=00000140  r=  1.60000000
[ 71, 21]  n=00000154  r=  1.70000000
[135, 22]  n=00000168  r=  1.80000000
[199, 23]  n=0000017c  r=  1.90000000
[  4,  0]  n=00000002  r=  2.00000000
```

Comment: Wow this is great! Thank you so much!